# python 3 - urllib issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm using python 3.3.0 in Windows 7.
I have two files: dork.txt and fuzz.py

dork.txt contains following:

```
/about.php?id=1
/en/company/news/full.php?Id=232
/music.php?title=11
```

fuzz.py contains following:

```
srcurl = "ANY-WEBSITE"
drkfuz = open("dorks.txt", "r").readlines()
print("\n[+] Number of dork names to be fuzzed:",len(drkfuz))

for dorks in drkfuz:
    dorks = dorks.rstrip("\n")
    srcurl = "http://"+srcurl+dorks

    requrl = urllib.request.Request(srcurl) 

    #httpreq = urllib.request.urlopen(requrl)

    # Starting the request
    try:
        httpreq = urllib.request.urlopen(requrl)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as  e:
        print ("[!] Error code: ",  e.code)
        print("")
        #sys.exit(1)

    except urllib.error.URLError as  e:
        print ("[!] Reason: ",  e.reason)
        print("")
        #sys.exit(1)  

    #if e.code != 404:
    if httpreq.getcode() == 200:
        print("\n*****srcurl********\n",srcurl)
        return srcurl
```

So, when I enter the correct website name which has `/about.php?id=1`, it works fine.
But when I provide the website which has `/en/company/news/full.php?Id=232`, it first 
prints `Error code:  404` and then gives me the following error: `UnboundLocalError: local 
variable 'e' referenced before assignment` or `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'httpreq' referenced before assignment`

I can understand that if the website doesn't have the page which contains `/about.php?id=1`, it gives `Error code:  404` but why  it's not going back in the `for` loop to check the remaining dorks in the text file??? Why it stops here and throws an error?

I want to make a script to find out valid page from just a website address like: `www.xyz.com`

Comment: Its better to understand more about the scope of variables. That makes you solve these type of issues.

Comment: @codelover, Thanks for motivating me to learn about scope of variables. But currently could you please solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the line `urllib.request.urlopen(requrl)` expression throws an exception, the variable `httpreq` is never set. You could set it to `None` before the `try` statement, then test if it is still `None` afterwards:

```
httpreq = None

try:
    httpreq = urllib.request.urlopen(requrl)

# ...

if httpreq is not None and httpreq.getcode() == 200:
```

Comment: @Martijin, When I edited it like above, it still fails. It prints `Error code:  404` and gives error: `ValueError: unknown url type: None`
What's the mystery behind this?

Comment: @Martijin, I'm sure. Even I wrote `print` after that `if` statement. If I'm not wrong, it should not go in that if condition. It must go to `for` loop after throwing an error of `404`

Comment: I have no idea where that exception of yours now takes place (not without a full traceback). If you have an unhandled exception in your code, the `for` loop is terminated.

Comment: @Martijin, oops, my mistake it goes to the other file via `return srcurl`. I wonder if it goes to the `if condition` why it has not printed the contents of `print statement`? It has only printed `404` error! And it must move back to the `for loop` too! So, what would be wrong?

Comment: If there was a 404, then `httpreq` is still `None`, so the `if` condition is *not* executed and it goes on with the loop.

Comment: @Martijin, hey, you are right. It's not going to the `if` condition but again one more problem. Now url becomes like: `www.xyz.com/about.php?id=1/en/company/news/full.php?Id=232` when it executes second time. As you know, second time it must be like: `www.xyz.com/en/company/news/full.php?Id=232`. So, I'm trying hard to resolve this but no success. Please tell me how can I get rid out of it.

Comment: @magneto: That depends *entirely* on your `dorks.txt` file and what URLs do not return an error.

Comment: @Martijin, I have solved it on my own way. Simply, I put one more `if` condition in `except urllib.error.HTTPError as  e:` and again got the parsed url by `parseurl.netloc`.
Anyway, thanks for that solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
srcurl = "ANY-WEBSITE"
drkfuz = open("dorks.txt", "r").readlines()
print("\n[+] Number of dork names to be fuzzed:",len(drkfuz))

for dorks in drkfuz:
    dorks = dorks.rstrip("\n")
    srcurl = "http://"+srcurl+dorks

    try:
        requrl = urllib.request.Request(srcurl)
        if requrl != None and len(requrl) > 0:
            try:
                httpreq = urllib.request.urlopen(requrl)
                if httpreq.getcode() == 200:
                    print("\n*****srcurl********\n",srcurl)
                    return srcurl
            except:
                # Handle exception
                pass
    except:
        # Handle your exception
        print "Exception"
```

Untested code, but it will work logically.

Comment: not working! It throws this error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'requrl' referenced before assignment`
I think it might be due to `404`

Comment: Again it shows `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'requrl' referenced before assignment` 
I'm also trying different ways but I'm failing!

Comment: That you could fix it :( You might be using `'requrl'` outsite of `try:` that must be the reason

Comment: yeah, I fixed it. But after that it prints `Exception` twice and move out of the for loop. Even now, it's not working for previously working website! Please provide more details if you can.

Comment: send me any sample site which returns the url.